# How to declare scientific data type in my code

Tags: excel, vba, types

```
Sub Find_Value()
Dim FindString As Double
Dim Rng As Range``
FindString = InputBox("Enter a search value")
 If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
  With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
   Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
   After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
   LookIn:=xlValues, _
   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
   MatchCase:=False)
   If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Application.Goto Rng, True
   Else
    MsgBox "Nothing found"
   End If
  End With
 End If
End Sub
```

the inputbox from the code has to read the barcode data which usually gives data in this format "0.00000E+12". However, my present code just reads numbers...what do i do ? i am new to vba so... please help :)

Comment: There is no Scientific Data Type in either VBA or Excel. `LookIn:=xlValues` has some limitations. Try `LookIn:=xlFormulas` instead and enter the value however you get it from the barcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub Find_Value()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, FindString As String, Rng As Range, lastRow As Long

 Set sh = sheets("Sheet1")
 lastRow = sh.Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 FindString = InputBox("Enter a search value")
 If FindString = "" Then MsgBox "No input...": Exit Sub
 FindString = Trim(FindString) 'to trim spaces if they exist in the copied string...
 If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With sh.Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.cells(1), FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                After:=.cells(.cells.count), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220594/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-how-to-declare-scientific-data-type-in-my-code).